# Building argument list with an array

Tags: arrays, bash

I need to build up an argument list for `find` using values only known at run time. I'm trying to use an array to do so.

Below is a simplified version which uses hard coded values.  When I echo out the command it appears to be correct (and when I run it manually it does what I'd expect). When it enters the for-loop it appears to be running `find` (because I can see the same errors about `Permission denied` for directories owned by other users as when I run manually). But inside the for-loop, it doesn't echo out any of the `.txt` files that a manual run finds.

What did I do wrong?

```
#!/bin/bash

args=(/tmp -iname \"*.txt\")

#args+=(-o -iname \"*.jpg\")

echo command will be: find ${args[@]}
for f in $( find ${args[@]} ); do
    echo found $f
done
```

The accepted answer below correctly identified the issue. But if I add an additional `-iname` clause, my script "ignores" all but the last as detailed here:

```
#!/bin/bash

args=($1)
args+=(-maxdepth $2)
args+=(-iname "*$3")
args+=(-o -iname "*$4")
echo command will be: find "${args[@]}"

find "${args[@]}" -print 2>/dev/null | while read -r f; do
    echo found "$f"
done
```

For example, when called with `/home/me 2 .jpg .png` this correctly echoes that the command will be `find /home/me -maxdepth 2 -iname *.jpg -o -iname *.png` but then my script only echoes the `.png` files that it finds.

Comment: Quote your variables. (e.g. `"${args[@]}"`, "$f", etc.) Also don't read the output of find like that. http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001

Comment: Don't escape the quotes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't escape the quotes. That will make them literal, so it will try to find files whose names actually begin and end with doublequotes.

```
args=(/tmp -iname "*.txt")
```

Then you need to put quotes around `${args[@]}` to tell the shell that it should requote them when expanding the array:

```
find "(" "${args[@]}" ")" -print | while read -r f
do
    echo found "$f"
done
```

Comment: Thanks. I ran into another issue and added it to the question instead of sticking it in this comment since it allows for better formatting.

Comment: When you use `-o`, you need an action in each branch. I've fixed the answer to put parenthese around everything to group them.

Comment: Hm. Actually parens around all the args didn't work for me but parens around just the `-iname` clauses did. But the other answer that mentioned such parens disappeared...

Comment: If you have things in `$args` that need to be distributed among both branches of the `-o`, then you need additional levels of parentheses. E.g. if you want `-maxdepth` to apply to both `-iname` clauses, you need to put them in parentheses.

Answer (score 1):

Bash4 can expand globs recursively with `shopt -s globstar`.
Just use `array=(/tmp/**/*.txt)` to get all the elements.